# Full stop after why

Tags: grammaticality

I have a question regarding the use of the noun *why* in a sentence. 
Is it possible to use a full stop after why? For example, are these 2 sentences correct?

> **That's the reason why. I chose vegetarian food.**

I always knew that why can introduce a question or can be used as linked noun but someone told me that the sentence above is grammatically correct.

Comment: They are both acceptable (if one doesn't demand a 'proper sentence' for the first fragment). But they make as much sense as written as say 'Under the table. I chose to go swimming on Tuesday.'

Comment: Ya don't even need to USE the word WHY. What's wrong with "That's the reason I chose vegetarian food"? Don

Comment: I know that using "why" after "reason" is redoundant and "why"should be eliminated from the sentence. But if I decide to leave it, is it correct to end the sentence after "why"? For me it's a serius mistake, even more serius then leaving the noun.

Comment: Your two sentences make no sense. Correct: That's the reason why I chose vegetarian food. - You should ask such questions on  ELL.

Comment: "You ask me why I became vegetarian? I do not like meat, that is the reason why."

Comment: The reason why I chose vegetarian food is (that)......

Answer (score 3):

Grammatically correct, though perhaps not expressing what is intended.

> That's the reason why. I chose vegetarian food.

Is two separate statements. The first.

> That's the reason why.

Means the same thing as "That's the reason", but the redundant *why* can add emphasis or stress it's connection to a question that had asked "why?" This sentence only makes sense after a reason has been given.

> I chose vegetarian food.

States that you chose such food. It doesn't really relate to the previous sentence, unless perhaps underlining it or adding to it. E.g.:

> Why did you not try the speciality?
>
> The meat dishes all had sauces with chilli in them, and I'm allergic to chilli. That's the reason why. I chose vegetarian food.

First we've the explanation, then the "that's the reason why", and then the final sentence adds separate information.

Conversely,

> That's the reason why I chose vegetarian food.

Says of the previous statement not just "that's the reason" but "that's the reason for choosing vegetarian food.